# Swift - "Sign in Apple Button" not showing when I debug on real device

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, apple-sign-in, sign-in-with-apple

My app rejected by App Store because it doesn't have apple login button so I added "sign in with apple" button

[image]

Here is the issue;

When I debug my app on simulator, apple login button is showing and working as you see but when I debug it on a real device it's not showing.

I uploaded the app and tried via Testflight. Still same issue, that button is not showing.

Where exactly am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check your device os version? **ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton** available in ios 13 and more.

Comment: Oh now I see. How stupid of me. My device os version is 12. Thank you so much man!